# Kubeadm command not found

Tags: kubernetes

I've installed first [docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) then [Kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/), and finally [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/).
Now I want to run my cluster, but when I type `kubeadm init`

I get the following errror:

> kubeadm: command not found

Can someone help me?

Warok

Comment: what operating system are you working on?

Comment: Linux 16.04 freshly installed

Comment: where is kubeadm installed, `which kubeadm`? and what is your `PATH` variable set for ? Also, are you sure of running `apt-get update` or may be just re-run and try again.

Comment: `which kubeadm` give nothing and I $PATH contains : `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

Comment: Please consider posting it as an answer to your question and marking as an approved solution. It will help the community!

Answer (score 0):

Ho, apparently it was because of `apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl` command

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what I did.
I terminated the instance, spun up a new instance, executed the same set of commands to install docker and Kubernetes.
And now `kubeadm` is recognized.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).